# Spring Actuator Custom Metrics (avg, min, max response times)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, metrics, gauge

Is there a way to produce avg response time per request, min response time per request and max response time per request? I suppose I could use Atomic variables or synchronization per request to avoid race conditions but I am not sure if this is the best way.

Comment: You can add custom metrics using Spring `CounterService` and `GaugeService`.

Comment: Yes thank you, but these objects can only update a metric. There is no obvious way to store (in memory) and then access previous values in order to perform some actions (ie. compare, add, multiply, divide) before updating and storing again the value. I am looking for a thread safe way and all I have got until now is locking the application scope before applying these actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this problem is to use [dropwizard metrics](http://metrics.dropwizard.io/3.1.0/) Timer. Unfortunately we are facing the exact same issue described [here](https://github.com/dropwizard/metrics/issues/730) which is a limitation of the API. But overall this can do the job.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to record response time, you can get the time at the beginning and at the end of the handler, and then you update a GaugeService with the delta. 
In the case you want to save an history of this value, you can use a GaugeWriter to export the current data from your GaugeService.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately,  we use an older version of spring-actuator. What we need could be done with dropwizard metrics if they had more overloaded methods.